# Laravel eloquent where pivot null or less than

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have timestamp field, *named closed*, in pivot table for Many to Many relationship. I want to get items where *closed* is null or is less than a specific time.
I tried the following:

```
// In model
public function jobEquipments($job, $one = false)
    {
        $nowDt = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        if (!$one){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Equipment::class, 'cavity_actions', 'cavity_id', 'equipment_id')
                ->wherePivot('job_id', $job)
                ->withPivot('created_at','aid')
                ->wherePivot('closed',null)
                ->orWherePivot('closed','<',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc');
            }
....
```

I also tried to use `$nowDt` instead of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in `orWherePivot` However, there is no change to the query result. i.e It looks like the same values without `->orWherePivot('closed','<',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` clause. In my database, I'm pretty sure that there is enough records with closed datetime value less than `Now`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to isolate the `or` statements. Try this:

```
$this->belongsToMany(Equipment::class, 'cavity_actions', 'cavity_id', 'equipment_id')
                ->wherePivot('job_id', $job)
                ->withPivot('created_at','aid')
                ->where(function ($q) {
                    $q->where('cavity_actions.closed',null)
                      ->orWhere('cavity_actions.closed','<',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                })
                ->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc');
```

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orWherePivot()`

Comment: Ok, try to use Where and orWhere. I've edited the answer

Comment: The last edit works, but it returns the same result as my regarded code without isolation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to `dd()` the output of your code properly. It works fine man. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Works at least with *PostgreSQL* (*Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\PostgresGrammar*):

```php
# wherePivotIsNull
->wherePivot(SomeModelName::DELETED_AT, 'is not distinct from', DB::raw('null')

# wherePivotIsNotNull
->wherePivot(SomeModelName::DELETED_AT, 'is distinct from', DB::raw('null')
```